# TextExt jQuery Plugin And Hidden Field Value

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-textext

I have been playing with http://textextjs.com/ this weekend as it seems like a very solid autocomplete plugin with additional functionality that might be useful in the future (like tagging).  I tried implementing this in one location that is currently use my own autocomplete functionality however there is one critical issue for me with this plugin that I have yet to find an example/solution for.

I am using the following data structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Active",
        //etc....
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Inactive",
        //etc....
    },
    //etc...
]
```

Now I am using the ajax/autocomplete plugin right now (though I am going to need this functionality for the tags plugin eventually).  I have a custom ItemManager that allows this data this data to work just fine but here is my problem.  I want to be able to set the input that the users sees and interacts with to the the object.title however I want to have the hidden input that is submitted with the form to be object.id.  How do I get this type of functionality when using the autocomplete/tags plugin?

I have a tried to look at the onGetDataForm since it would seems like I would need to create a plugin that implements that (though to me it seems like overkill to have to create a plugin just to be able to set the hidden input different from the visible one) but even if that was the case, I don't see how I would get access to the full data object of the item selected in the autocomplete to be able to set the two field different.  Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Did you solved it ?!!I have the same problem\

Answer (score 1):

I don't think TextExt.js currently supports that, but it should be pretty easy to implement. Before I explain, please do file an issue in GitHub so that it eventually makes into (if you haven't already).

Have a look at this function https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/jquery-textext/blob/master/src/js/textext.plugin.autocomplete.js#L671

```
p.onGetFormData = function(e, data, keyCode)
{
    var self       = this,
        val        = self.val(),
        inputValue = val,
        formValue  = val
        ;
    data[100] = self.formDataObject(inputValue, formValue);
};
```

As you can see, it returns values from the input box directly. What you can do here is check in your data array (`self._suggestions`) if what user has typed so far matches something. If that's the case you can use the item that matches and return `id` field.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: can you provide me an example!!?